# Replacing the slide image with another image in a slideshow(Jquery Cycle) using Javascript

Tags: jquery-plugins

I have 10 images that are displayed as a slideshow using the Jquery Cycle plugin. 
At a time 4 images are displayed . When the user clicks the next button the next 4 images are displayed.

Under each image there is a dropdown. When I select an item in the dropdown I want to change the image to some other image depending on the item the user has selected in the dropdowm.

I also need to change the 'href' of the image when the user selects another item in the dropdown.

When the user selects an item in the dropdown I using the javascript code   given below to change the image and other details

Javascript Code

```
document.getElementById('prodLink' + productId).href = "productDetails.aspx?id=" + productAttributeValueId;

            document.getElementById('prodImageLink' + productId).href = "productDetails.aspx?id=" + productAttributeValueId;
            document.getElementById('prodImage' + productId).src = "ProductImages/" + productImage;
            document.getElementById('prodImage' + productId).className=document.getElementById('prodImage' + productId).className;
            document.getElementById('prodNameLink' + productId).href = "productDetails.aspx?id=" + productAttributeValueId;
            document.getElementById('productPrice' + productId).innerHTML = productPrice;
            document.getElementById('prodAttribute' + productId).innerHTML = attributeValue;
```

**The HTML Code**

```
<div class="cycle-slideshow" data-cycle-fx="scrollHorz" data-cycle-timeout="0"
  data-cycle-slides="&gt; ul" data-cycle-prev="div.pagers a.latest_prev" data-cycle-next=
  "div.pagers a.latest_nxt">
    <ul class="product_show">
      <li class="column">
        <div class="img">
          <div class="hover_over">
            <a class="link" href="#">link</a> <a class="cart" href="#">cart</a>
          </div><a href="#"><img src="images/photos/4c_pic8.jpg" width="218" height="207"
          alt="" /></a>
        </div><a href="#" style="line-height:14px;">Product 1,<br />
        1 Kg Pouch<br /></a> <span class="ourPrice">Our Price: $121.20</span><span class=
        "saveText"><br /></span>

        <div class="dropdowndiv">
          <select name="search_category1" class="default" tabindex="1" style=
          "color: #333333;">
            <option value="">
              Pack size
            </option>

            <option value="amazed">
              Amazed
            </option>


          </select>
        </div><br />
        <br />
        <label for="textfield">Qty</label> <input type="text" name="textfield" id=
        "textfield" class="carttextbox" /> &nbsp; <img src="images/img/but_addtocart.png"
        alt="" width="72" height="16" align="absmiddle" /><br />
        <br />
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the modified working javascript code  that changes the image(and some other information) in a Jquery Cycle2 slideshow

I added $('.cycle-slideshow').cycle('destroy'); before changing any information

After that I change all the required information

Then I call  $('.cycle-slideshow').cycle(); to recreate the slideshow

```
$('.cycle-slideshow').cycle('destroy');
            document.getElementById('prodLink' + productId).href = "productDetails.aspx?id=" + productAttributeValueId;

            document.getElementById('prodImageLink' + productId).href = "productDetails.aspx?id=" + productAttributeValueId;
            document.getElementById('prodImage' + productId).src = "ProductImages/" + productImage;
            document.getElementById('prodImage' + productId).className=document.getElementById('prodImage' + productId).className;
            document.getElementById('prodNameLink' + productId).href = "productDetails.aspx?id=" + productAttributeValueId;
            document.getElementById('productPrice' + productId).innerHTML = productPrice;
            document.getElementById('prodAttribute' + productId).innerHTML = attributeValue;



            $('.cycle-slideshow').cycle();
```